# unix: overwriting a file written by another user in same group

Tags: unix, file-permissions

OS: Ubuntu 12.04

I have a directory what has given write permission to group `foo`. Two users `bar` and `baz` are part of the group. Both can successfully write files to the directory. However, `baz` cannot overwrite a file (i.e. create a file with the same name) that was written by `bar`. I'm doing the file I/O through Python (csv module), but I don't think that has anything to do with this problem.

How do I set permissions so that `bar` and `baz` can overwrite eachother's files in the `foo` directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the mode of the directory to setgid to ensure that new files are created with the same group as that owning the directory.  See this article for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid .

The command is: `chmod g+s /path/to/directory`

Answer (score 0):

When user creates file, the default permissions don't allow write to group. You need to change the `umask` so newly created files will have write permissions for group:

```
umask 0002
```

To know what is the current umask, run it without args.

See [man umask](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/umask.2.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @shimon! I just ran umask in the foo directory with no args, it returned 0002

Comment: AFAIK, You set it once and it persists until you change it..

Comment: umask only limits the max permissions so if the application doesn't request group write then umask has no effect.